# How do I declare method openConnection() in Android studio because I get this error that says " cannot resolve method 'openConnection();'

Tags: java, android, methods, server, httpurlconnection

How do I  declare method openConnection() in Android studio because I get this error that says " cannot resolve method 'openConnection();'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpT6f.png)...

Comment: Please show the list of `import`s at the top of that file.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with this line:

```
URI url = new URI(register_url);
```

From the code, it would appear you mixed up `URI` nad `URL`, and were actually trying to create a `URL` object:

```
URL url = new URL(register_url);
```

`URL`, unlike `URI`, does have an `openConnection` method.